# send print to local printer using printer name without opening printer selection dialogue box from website

Tags: javascript, java, php, angular

I want  to send print to local printer using printer name without opening printer selection dialogue box from website in javascript/php/angular/java. Can anybody help me to find solution? 
thanks

Comment: you can't - because a web page can't access that sort of information - i.e. what printers are available - if and where something prints is always be under end user control and your website can't change that

Comment: If the website runs locally, PHP can print files. Either by accessing the printer directly, or by running a system command. Printing from the browser always opens the dialog box. (also Java !== JavaScript)

Comment: no website not running on local host

Comment: @ChrisG is right. What you can do is create an exe file and map it your registry protocols.
Then use asynchronous pluggable protocol handler from your website which will run the executable.
Keep in mind that for this to work, the exe file must be installed and mapped in the registry.